# Xamarin.Forms on iOS: Shrink height of page instead of shifting it up when the softkeyboard appears

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, soft-keyboard

Got the problem that the softkeyboard overlaps an entry field placed at the bottom.

[image]

XAML code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,0.9">
            <Label Text="Heading" />
        </ScrollView>
        <Entry x:Name="SearchEntry" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,1,1,.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Placeholder="Suchen..." ReturnType="Done" />            
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I installed the [KeyboardOverlap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Forms.KeyboardOverlap/)! plugin via nuget. It shifts the whole page upwards till the entry is visible again. The entry is visible, but the top of the page isn't visible anymore because it's shifted up.

Another often mentioned solution is wrapping the pages's content in a ScrollView. Because I definitively need an AbsoluteLayout as root content, that's unfortunately not a solution.

I'm looking for a solution which shrinks the height of the page and don't just shifts it up when the softkeyboard appears.

Why I need this? The page is filled dynmically with search result based on the entrie's input. If there are only few result, they're not visible because of the page's upward shift. The user could think that there aren't any search results. Displaying a text like 'No search results.' above the entry would be a simple solution but is not an option here.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to describe the page? I'm confused about your description, where is the entry, above or bottom of page?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Sure, sorry for the confusion.
I don't know why but it's working now. I could remove KeyboardOverlap from nuget and the entry is still shifting up when the softkeyboard apperas.Should I remove the question?

Comment: It may caused by the KeyboardOverlap? That's depending on you, you can keep it here.

Comment: My mistake. I have [this](https://github.com/adamped/SoftInput/blob/master/SoftInput/SoftInput.iOS/Render/KeyboardRender.cs) code in my iOS project. I didn't know it's already active because of few experience with custom renderers, thought I have to write some additional code in my shared project to make the renderer work. Will there be a perfomance impact because the renderer is called for every page but actually I only need it for one page?

Comment: If you only need this impact one page, you should create a custom page and then create custom redener for this page. Have a look at example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage). You use `Page` in the custom renderer now and it will affect all the content pages because `ContentPage` inherit from `Page`.

Comment: Changing line 14 to `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ConcretePageName), typeof(KeyboardRender))]` did the trick. `ConcretePageName` is my search page class (see screenshot from the question) wich inherits from `ContentPage`. So now extra work needed in the shared project.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want to say.

Comment: All right, thank you for the great help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using this [CustomRenderer](https://github.com/adamped/SoftInput/blob/master/SoftInput/SoftInput.iOS/Render/KeyboardRender.cs) class in the iOS project instead of the KeyboardOverlap plugin did the trick.

Don't forget to customize line 14 with your concrete page classname(s) where you need the functionality. Otherwise the renderer is called for all pages in your app!

Many thanks to [Jack Hua - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10539446/jack-hua-msft)!